# Headless chrome fails in windows container, require DXAVDA dll's even when using --headless switch

Tags: windows, docker, google-chrome, headless

I am trying to run chrome headless within a windows container, however chrome crashes stating it's missing a number of DXVAVDA libraries. However I am passing the --disable-gpu flag so not sure why it would require them. Any ideas? The container is running on a Windows Server 2019 vm

```
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 powershell
```

Then once in the container install chocolatey and then chrome

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
choco install googlechrome -y
```

Then run chrome headless

```
 & 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' --headless --disable-gpu --enable-logging --v=1 --dump-dom https:\\www.chromestatus.com

PS C:\> [0211/141947.811:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(226)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0
[0211/141947.865:VERBOSE1:webrtc_internals.cc(117)] Could not get the download directory.
[0211/141947.879:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(873)] MSM::InitializeMaybeAsync([this=00006DDE0028DF80])
[0211/141947.881:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(873)] MDM::MediaDevicesManager()
[0211/141947.882:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(873)] MSM::MediaStreamManager([this=00006DDE0028DF80]))
[0211/141948.048:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1461)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: mf.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[0211/141948.051:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1461)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: mfplat.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[0211/141948.055:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1461)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: ms
```

Comment: Hi @AJ, did you find any solutions to this?

Comment: Still no solution unfortunately

Comment: It seems to work if you use the windows:1809 image. Given 1809+ images allow gpu pass through it would appear that chrome is not fully supporting the --headless option any more. Trouble is windows images are already large and this one is even more massive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome on Windows docker container is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948655/chrome-on-windows-docker-container-is-not-working)

Comment: @JuanM.Elosegui - thanks for the tip, that wasn't the solution unfortunately - I had already fixed the font issue (it shows in the logs after the missing dll's) by mapping the the local fonts to the container with -v c:\windows\fonts:c:\windows\fonts (yes I know thats not the safest method)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error which went away after I added this chrome command line argument:

```
--disable-software-rasterizer
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same DXVAVDA missing library errors running chromedriver on Windows 10 enterprise N (a version which infamously does not include "media related technologies"). I then installed the Media Feature Pack for Windows 10 N (May 2019) found here (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/media-feature-pack-for-windows-10-n-may-2019-e3b42214-1186-503a-4f57-0e8d538bc025) and these errors went way.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to missing fonts in the 2019 core base image.
Check out [this](https://github.com/gantrior/docker-chrome-windows) repo on how to install the missing fonts